# Python 3: Creating list of multiple dictionaries have same keys but different values coming from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm parsing through a response of XML using xpath from lxml library.
I'm getting the results and creating lists out of them like below:

```
object_name = [o.text for o in response.xpath('//*[name()="objectName"]')]
object_size_KB = [o.text for o in response.xpath('//*[name()="objectSize"]')]
```

I want to use the lists to create a dictionary per element in list and then add them to a final list like this:

```
[{'object_name': 'file1234', 'object_size_KB': 9347627},
{'object_name': 'file5671', 'objeobject_size_KBt_size': 9406875}]
```

I wanted a generator because I might need to search for more metadata from the response in the future so I want my code to be future proof and reduce repetition:

```
meta_names = {
'object_name': '//*[name()="objectName"]',
'object_size_KB': '//*[name()="objectSize"]'
             }
def parse_response(response, meta_names):
"""
input: response: api xml response text from lxml xpath
input: meta_names: key names used to generate dictionary per object
return: list of objects dictionary
"""
    mylist = []
   # create list of each xpath match assign them to variables
    for key, value in meta_names.items():
        mylist.append({key: [o.text for o in response.xpath(value)]})
    return mylist
```

However the function gives me this:

```
[{'object_name': ['file1234', 'file5671']}, {'object_size_KB': ['9347627', '9406875']}]
```

I've been searching for a similar case in the forums but couldn't find something to match my needs.
Appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:** Renneys answer was what I wanted I just adjusted the length value of range of my results since I don't always have the same length of xpath per object key and since my lists have identical length everytime I picked first index [0].
now the function looks like this.

```
def create_entries(root, keys):
    tmp = []
    for key in keys:
        tmp.append([o.text for o in root.xpath('//*[name()="' + key + '"]')])
    ret = []
    # print(len(tmp[0]))
    for i in range(len(tmp[0])):
        add = {}
        for j in range(len(keys)):
            add[keys[j]] = tmp[j][i]
        ret.append(add)
    return ret
```

Comment: i don't understand, why do you want separate dicts?

Comment: So I can loop over every dict to create a body to index in elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two dimensional array:

```
def createEntries(root, keys):
    tmp = []
    for key in keys:
        tmp.append([o.text for o in root.xpath('//*[name()="' + key + '"]')])
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(tmp)):
        add = {}
        for j in range(len(keys)):
            add[keys[j]] = tmp[j][i]
        ret.append(add)
    return ret
```

Comment: Looks good but throwing error: IndexError: list index out of range for line: add[keys[j]] = tmp[j][i]

Comment: Are the results for each xpath array of the same length? So do you have the same amount of values for "objectName", "objectSize", ...? If not, that's the problem here. The only part that can cause this error is the tmp[j][i] since keys[j] and tmp[j] are existing due to the way j and the lists are defined.

Comment: No the length of each list of xpath can be any number. I see what you mean if I get 5 results instead of what I had before 2. It matches the length of the arrays of tmp and add. However I might get 5 or even 500,000 results per xpath. note that all lists are with same length e.g: objectName length = objectSize length etc. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Well just do an additional check then, if len(tmp[j]) < i. And only then evaluate tmp[j][i].

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

You can use zip to combine your two lists into a list of value pairs.
Then, you can use a list comprehension or a generator expression to pair your value pairs with your desired keys.

```
import pprint

object_name = ['file1234', 'file5671']
object_size = [9347627, 9406875]

[{'object_name': 'file1234', 'object_size_KB': 9347627},
{'object_name': 'file5671', 'objeobject_size_KBt_size': 9406875}]

[{'object_name': ['file1234', 'file5671']}, {'object_size_KB': ['9347627', '9406875']}]

# List Comprehension
obj_list = [{'object_name': name, 'object_size': size} for name,size in zip(object_name,object_size)]

pprint.pprint(obj_list)
print('\n')


# Generator Expression
generator = ({'object_name': name, 'object_size': size} for name,size in zip(object_name,object_size))

for obj in generator:
  print(obj)
```

Live Code Example -> https://onlinegdb.com/SyNSwd7jU

---

I think the accepted answer is more efficient, but here's an example of how list comprehensions could be used.

```
meta_names = {
'object_name': ['file1234', 'file5671'],
'object_size_KB': ['9347627', '9406875'],
'object_text': ['Bob', 'Ross']
             }

def parse_response(meta_names):
  """
  input: response: api xml response text from lxml xpath
  input: meta_names: key names used to generate dictionary per object
  return: list of objects dictionary
  """
  # List comprehensions
  to_dict = lambda l: [{key:val for key,val in pairs} for pairs in l]

  objs = list(zip(*list([[key,val] for val in vals] for key,vals in meta_names.items())))

  pprint.pprint(to_dict(objs))  

parse_response(meta_names)
```

Live Code -> https://onlinegdb.com/ryLq4PVjL

Comment: Hi Evan, What if I don't know my keys before hand and want to pass them as dictionary to a function then generate the lists per xpath then get the final list like in the function in my question? note the keys : object_name, object_size are not the only keys I have they could be way more than that such as object_status, object_deleted etc..

Comment: Ah, my new solution should work if you'd like another example.

Comment: Thanks Evan, Looks really solid. But I also accepted the answer of  @Rennney because he tackled xpath matching as well. So I didn't need to use to functions to achieve what I needed. Thanks for getting back with another answer